# Couchbase SDK 2.7 setRemove() method not deletin records from couchbase DB

Tags: java, couchbase, couchbase-java-api

I have a below code snippet to set remove the document. But I could see it is not deleting or removing documents from couchbase.

```
bucket.setRemove(key, String.valueOf(instanceList.get(0)),
                      MutationOptionBuilder.builder().expiry(1).createDocument(false));
```

This is the one thing. Another thing where I will get a list of documents for a single key and I want to delete only a particular document for that key whats the best approach.

e.g

```
"key_test",
                    [
  {
    "fields": [
      "ram",
      "sham",
      "birthdate",
     "dept1"
    ]
  },
  {
    "fields": [
      "Kiran",
      "sharm",
      "birthdate2",
     "dept2"
    ]
  }
]
```

From Here I want to delete the document which contains **"ram"** value.

> Note:- I have created Index as well to delete expired documents.

Comment: This seems like two questions. First, I don't think `setRemove` is the right operation to remove a document. Try just `remove`: https://docs.couchbase.com/java-sdk/2.7/document-operations.html#java-removing-full-docs

Comment: Second part, you want to remove *all* document which have "ram" in the `fields` array? You'll probably need a N1QL query for this (assuming you're using a relatively recent version of Couchbase Server): https://docs.couchbase.com/server/6.5/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/delete.html

Comment: @MatthewGroves setRemove() is also a method to set document as removable with some TTL in above example I mentioned TTL as 1ms.

Comment: setRemove() method is there in Couchbase SDK to modify the document and in the above code, we are setting the TTL to 1ms.

Comment: @MaheshwarLigade Matthew Groves is correct.  The setRemove() call is to remove a value from a set within a document.  You want the remove() call, which actually removes a document.

Comment: @GrahamPople and MattewGroves in the setremove method, I am setting TTL for that document as 1ms

Comment: @MaheshwarLigade that's interesting, why use a TTL in that way, rather than simply removing it?
How are you determining that the document isn't removed?